# The square of 43

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> I am a square,
>
> I am made in the year square of 43,
>
> also, 106 years after my second child was born
>
> also, in a year with the number 43.
>
> People pay with me a square amount of dollars.

Comment: Are the children you mention also square?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are

> Franklin

I am a square,
I am made in the year square of 43,

> Franklin Square (of Franklin and Blackstone Squares in Boston) opened in 1849 (which is 43 squared)

also, 106 years after my second child was born

also, in a year with the number 43.

> Benjamin Franklin's second child was born in 1743, 106 years before 1849

People pay with me a square amount of dollars.

> Benjamin Franklin is on the 100 dollar bill, and 100 is 10 squared.

Comment: And hes a "square", lol.

Comment: I had the Franklin square itself in mind, but whatever.